# sbt-assembly: deduplicate error with pom.properties

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt 0.13.7 and sbt-assembly 0.12.0.

Here are the error messages during "sbt assembly":

```
[error] (sse/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/arunswami/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:META-INF/maven/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/pom.properties
[error] /Users/arunswami/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:META-INF/maven/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/pom.properties
```

Here is the relevant section of my build.sbt file based on README at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "pom.properties" =>
    MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

What should I be doing instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your merge strategy looks ok, but the error message says `sse/*:assembly`.
Is your merge strategy included as part of the sse project?

Comment: You are correct! I didn't realize that the merge strategy had to be part of the project. I had it at the global level. Making it part of the project fixes the problem. Thanks!